# sudo -u not getting path appended in $HOME/.profile

Tags: bash, scripting, sudo

I have as script that requires root privileges. I run the script using `sudo ./script.sh`. Some parts of the script need to actually run as the original user, so I use `sudo --user=$SUDO_USER` inside the script to do that work. The problem I'm having is that I have some utilities installed for the user, and their path is appended to $PATH in my `~/.profile`. I get the feeling that ~/.profile is not executed when running as sudo, confirmed by `sudo --user=$SUDO_USER echo $PATH`.

I can get around this by sourcing $HOME/.profile, but this doesn't seem like the right solution:

```
sudo --user=$SUDO_USER source $HOME/.profile; command_i_want_to_run
```

Should I be appending my $PATH in a different file in order to make it available no matter the context?

Comment: Can you call the utility with an absolute path in your script? From a security standpoint, it is usually recommended not to rely on $PATH (although many scripts do it), so you would actually adhere to security best practices if you do that.

Comment: I want this script to be flexible enough that it can be called from different users on different systems. On machine the script might live in /home/pete/../bin and another might be in /home/otheruser/.../vendor/bin, for example. But it should be discoverable via $PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `bashrc` or similar configuration files are not sourced, is that sudo does not run a shell. It actually forks the process and does some other things - so it's not necessarily related to a shell at all. If you want to read this in more detail, search for `Process model` in `man sudo`.

I can think of two sensible options that are available to you:

1. You can tell sudo to use a login shell
2. You can execute bash using sudo and tell bash to be a login shell

The two achieve the same thing in a slightly different way.

**Option 1:**
`sudo --user=baam -i echo '$PATH'` will tell sudo to start the default shell of `baam` and execute `echo $PATH`. Note the quotes around `$PATH` in the original command, otherwise it will be expanded *before* bash sees it.

**Option 2:** `sudo --user=baam bash -c -l 'echo $PATH'` will use sudo to execute bash. The `-l` flag tells bash to act as a login shell, so it will source `.profile`. This is the better solution in my opinion, because you can also specify another shell that supports the `-l` flag, such as `zsh`, so you're more flexible overall.

Comment: Good answer, but one caveat: if you allow calling bash via sudo, you have to be very careful to craft a sudoers file that does not open a barnhole-sized security hole. And of course you would never want to simply allow "ALL" in a sudoers file (outside of a home-user setting, of course).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it depends on local sudoers policy, but at least on my Ubuntu system you can use the sudo `-i` or `--login` option to specify a login shell:

```
 -i, --login
             Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐
             base entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
             resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the
             shell.
```

So for example

```
$ sudo sudo -u steeldriver sh -c 'echo $PATH'
[sudo] password for steeldriver: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

but

```
$ sudo sudo -iu steeldriver sh -c 'echo $PATH'
/home/steeldriver/bin:/home/steeldriver/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```